# Drupal 8 convert json to Array

Tags: 8

I´m getting data from web service in Drupal 8:

```
$uri = "http://localhost:8888/drupal8/tipo_receta.json";
 try {
    $response = \Drupal::httpClient()->get($uri, array('headers' => array('Accept' => 'application/json')));
    $data = (string) $response->getBody();
    if (empty($data)) {
      return FALSE;
    }else{
        print $data;
    }
  }
  catch (RequestException $e) {
      return FALSE;
  }
```

I have this JSON source:

```
{
    "document_type ": "receta",
    "recipe_doc_id ": 1,
    "recipe_title": "Título de la receta",
    "recipe_description": "Descripción con todos los pasos de una receta",
    "recipe_ingredients": [
        {
            "ingredient_doc_id": 33,
            "ingredient_doc_hid": "ing_pera",
            "ingredient_name": "pera",
            "ingredient_value": "2 peras"
        },
        {
            "ingredient_doc_id": 54,
            "ingredient_doc_hid": "ing_manzana",
            "ingredient_name": "manzana",
            "ingredient_value": "300 grs. De Manzana"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my result on the page:

```
C:\wamp64\www\drupal8\core\themes\bartik\bartik.theme:142:string '{
    "document_type ": "receta",
    "recipe_doc_id ": 1,
    "recipe_title": "Título de la receta",
    "recipe_description": "Descripción con todos los pasos de una receta",
    "recipe_ingredients": [
        {
            "ingredient_doc_id": 33,
            "ingredient_doc_hid": "ing_pera",
            "ingredient_name": "pera",
            "ingredient_value": "2 peras"
        },
        {
            "ingredient_doc_id": 54,
            "ingredient_doc_hid": "ing_manzana",
         '...
```

How can i get an array so i could filter the data like this?

```
if($data['recipe_doc_id'] == "1"){
print $data['recipe_title'];
}
```

Comment: Can [Json::decode()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Component!Serialization!Json.php/function/Json%3A%3Adecode/8.2.x) help?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the [`Json::decode()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Component!Serialization!Json.php/function/Json%3A%3Adecode/8.2.x) method:

```
use Drupal\Component\Serialization\Json;

...

$decoded = Json::decode($data);
```